# Perl -- command executing inside a script hangs

Tags: perl, shell, command-line

When I run the following script, it does exactly what I want it to do and exits:

setDisplay.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

Xvfb -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/ :22 -screen 0 1024x768x16 2>&1 &
export DISPLAY=:22
```

When I run `./setDisplay.sh`, everything works fine.

OK, here's where the fun starts...

I have a Perl script that calls setDisplay...

Here is the eamorr.pl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $homeDir="/home/eamorr/Dropbox/site/";

my $cmd;
my $result;

print "-----Setting display...\n";
$cmd="sh $homeDir/setDisplay.sh";
print $cmd."\n";
$result=`$cmd`;
print $result;
```

It just hangs when I run `./eamorr.pl`

I'm totally stuck...

Comment: using `sh` when the shebanh is `bash` is generally  a bad idea .

Comment: No idea, but if that's all you're perl script is doing, you could just do an `exec $cmd;`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$result=`$cmd`;
```

a pipe is created connecting the perl process to the external command, and perl reads from that pipe until EOF.

Your external command creates a background process which still has the pipe on its stdout (and also its stderr since you did `2>&1`). There will be no EOF on that pipe until the background process exits or closes its stdout and stderr or redirects them elsewhere.

If you intend to collect the stdout and stderr of `Xvfb` into the perl variable `$result`, you'll naturally have to wait for it to finish. If you didn't intend that, I can't guess what you were trying to do with the `2>&1`.

Also a script that ends with an `export` command is suspect. It can only modify its *own* environment, and then it immediately exits so there's no noticeable effect. Usually that's a sign that someone is trying to modify the parent process's environment, which is not possible.